# Filter Date on Power Apps Gallery

Tags: gallery, powerapps

I have this formula in a column in a gallery that returns a date.

Substitute(ThisItem.DateWorked,"0:00:00","")

This returns the date formatted in the column like this: 4/17/2023.

I would to be able to filter on this column using a dropdown with dates that are formatted in the same way.

If(IsBlank(ReconcileWorkdateStartDate.Value)=false, Filter(tbl_TimeSaved, Substitute(ThisItem.EmployeeNo,"Text","")=ReconcileWorkdateStartDate))

When I try to do this, I receive this error below:

Name is not valid. 'ThisItem isn't recognized. The Substitute function has some invalid arguments.

Answer (score 0):

`ThisItem` is an operator that returns the item within a gallery (i.e., for each row). I'm assuming you have a gallery with the Items property set to some table, and one of the properties of that table is called 'DateWorked'. In this case, within the gallery you use `ThisItem.DateWorked` to access that value for each row of your table.

If you are outside a gallery (such as trying to set the Items property of a dropdown), you don't need the `ThisItem` identifier, as the property is already within scope of the Filter call:

```
Filter(
  tbl_TimeSaved,
  ReconcileWorkdateStartDate = ...
)
```

You can use the `ThisRecord` specifier to access those *scope values*, but it is not necessary:

```
Filter(
  tbl_TimeSaved,
  ThisRecord.ReconcileWorkdateStartDate = ...
)
```

There is also another problem in your expression as shown in the question: 'ReconcileWorkdateStartDate' is seen both as a record (argument to IsBlank, with a property called 'Value') and a text value (being compared to the result of Substitute)

```
If(
  IsBlank(ReconcileWorkdateStartDate.Value) = false,
  Filter(
    tbl_TimeSaved,
    Substitute(ThisItem.EmployeeNo,"Text","") = ReconcileWorkdateStartDate
  )
)
```

A related note: if the type of ThisItem.DateWorked is a date/time value not a string), then the best way to format it in a specific format is to use the Text function, such as `Text(ThisItem.DateWorked, "m/d/yyyy")` - this way you don't have to rely on the default date-to-text conversion which may not give you the format the Substitute function is expecting, especially if there are users in other locales. If it is already a string then your option with Substitute is the best one.

Comment: When I changed it to Text(ThisItem.DateWorked, "m/d/yyyy")  I still get the date and the time 4/17/2023 0:00:00....This is why I used Substitute to remove the time from the date.

Comment: Ah, then DateWorked is a text value, not a date. In this case your solution is correct. I'll update the answer to account for that.